# Stylus mixin doesnt work

Tags: css, stylus

I'm trying to do the following transition mixin:

```
transition(number = 0.2s)
-webkit-transition all number linear
-moz-transition all number linear
-o-transition all number linear
-ms-transition all number linear
transition:all number linear
```

But my output is:

```
.partners li:hover {
    -webkit-transition: all all linear;
    -moz-transition: all all linear;
    -o-transition: all all linear;
    -ms-transition: all all linear;
    transition: all all linear;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a mixin so you don't want to repeat yourself. So only give a argument (in your case (0.2s) when 'calling' the mixin not when creating it.

```
transition(number)
  -webkit-transition all number linear
  -moz-transition all number linear
  -o-transition all number linear
  -ms-transition all number linear
  transition:all number linear

.partners li:hover
  transition(0.2)
```

Should create the following CSS. Is this what you want?

```
.partners li:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2 linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2 linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2 linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2 linear;
  transition: all 0.2 linear;
}
```

Also check [nib](http://tj.github.io/nib/) for easier cross-browsers mixins.

Comment: I set the transition to 0.2s so i can call only transition() and the default value will be 0.2s. Your example doesnt work since "s" is needed in the number of the transition